# How to use a 3rd party DLL in a C++ DLL project?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, dll-reference, project-properties

In Visual Studio 2015, how do I properly set up a C++ DLL project that in turn refers to a 3rd party DLL (also implemented in C++)? I cannot add the 3rd party DLL to the references as it seems for a DLL project the "Browse..." option in the "Add reference..." window is missing (as opposed to the "Add reference..." window of an EXE project where there is such a "Browse..." button). As a consequence I cannot build the project. Is there another way to add that reference? Thanks for helping!

Comment: You talk about this as though it is a C# or VB.NET project but what you describe is normal for a C++ project.  It matters, don't force us to guess.  No, msbuild is powerless to discover dependencies of native executables.  If that DLL is not located on the PATH so the OS can find it then you have to help.  Just xcopy /d in the postbuild event.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention it's a C++ project. Thanks for making me aware of it! Question edited...

Comment: Programmers are constantly being confusing by saying _DLL_ and _DLL project_ and are constantly confused by _DLL_ and _DLL project_ when the type of DLL is not defined. There are native DLLs (the original, raw format) and there are COM DLLs and there are .Net Class Library DLLs. If my [Native Windows Dynamic Link Libraries (DLLs)](http://simplesamples.info/CPluPlus/NativeWindowsDynamicLinkLibraries.aspx) helps then I can post some of that as an answer. You cannot make a reference to a native style DLL.